# C++ Concatenate

Tags: c++

What's the best way (best practice) to append one LPWSTR/LPTSTR to another, without having to convert to something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will probably want to use [`strcat_s` and friends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d45bbxx4.aspx), which are length-checked versions of [`strcat` and friends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1x0y282.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

LPSTR == char* so You could just use strncat

with LPWSTR instead of strncat use just wcsncat

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tbyd7s1y.aspx